# React Native Android Slow Performance without Chrome Debug

Tags: react-native

I am having performance issues on React Native Android. I am using Redux.

The issue is that my app works fine (fast) when chrome debug is on. The moment i turn off the remote debugger, the performance becomes very sluggish. I was just wondering if this is normal. I have read other thread saying that in debug mode, the performance is executed on chrome itself so it's faster. Is such a big gap in performance normal?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? I got this same issue on IOS device (ipad4,ios10). I comment all console.log but that didn't work for me. The app still very slow whenever debugger is off.

Comment: I have same problem. Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I have head the same performance issues and that was quite bad experience. You need to remove any `console.log('show_me_some_data')` and then you will get better performance. I think react-native is trying to find remote debugger every time then he meets `console.log`. React need time for this and that's why performance is reduced. This is just my suggestion, but that worked for me.

Hope this will help someone.